# Firefox Android Addon: Add search engine

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-android

I've created an extension with the following manifest to add a search engine to Firefox.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Google Browse by Name search engine",
  "description": "Adds a search engine that searches Google using its Browse by Name feature",
  "version": "1.0",
  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "strict_min_version": "55.0"
    }
  },
  "chrome_settings_overrides": {
    "search_provider": {
      "name": "Browse by Name",
      "search_url": "https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q={searchTerms}",
      "keyword": "bbn",
      "favicon_url": "https://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
      "is_default": false
    }
  }
}
```

This works as expected on Firefox desktop, adding an option to the list of enabled search engines. However, it does not appear to work on Firefox Android, I assume because `chrome_settings_overrides` is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Differences_between_desktop_and_Android#Other_UI_related_API_and_manifest.json_key_differences) on [Android](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/chrome_settings_overrides#Browser_compatibility).

Addons making use of the legacy API appear to work correctly (e.g. [Startpage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/android/addon/startpage-https-privacy-search/)), adding search engines to the Android browser, but since Firefox is dropping support for legacy (non webextension) extensions this is no longer a solution.

What is the correct way to add a search engine to Firefox for Android using an addon?

I am aware that users can add a search engine available on a webpage by long-pressing on its search field, but I would like to offer an extension to automatically install the search engine (and save users from having to find a page offering the correct search field).

Comment: You wait until `chrome_settings_overrides` is implemented for Android. Find/file a bug asking for the implementation. Implement a [WebExtension Experiment](https://webextensions-experiments.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which adds this feature.

Comment: @Makyen Thanks, I'd not heard of webextension experiments, and also thought there might be an alternative API which I was missing. I'll look into doing what you've suggested.

Comment: I wish there was an alternative. Unfortunately, Smolderfox (FF57+), only has WebExtensions.